# How to match three formats of dates

Tags: javascript

How do i match dates in format DD_MM_YYYY and MM_YYYY and also YYYY

My strings are actually like these

`a-nice-text/22_10_2020.html`

`another-nice-text/10_2020.html`

`Just-another-text/2020.html`

I'm currently doing this:

`str.match(/\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{4}\.html/)`

but it's only matching string with 22_10_2020.html

Comment: Write a regular expression for every case and combine them with `|`

Comment: Sites like https://regex101.com might be handy in understanding and testing your regular expressions

Comment: @Andreas Alright, i had thought that could be possible with one regular expression. Thank you.

Comment: The "or" operator (`|`) also exists for regular expressions ;)

Comment: If the dates are always before `.html` could  think of it differently and just take what's after last `/` and before `.html`

Comment: if you want something other than regex, you can: `stringArr=string.split("/"); dateString=stringArr.pop().split(".")[0];`

Comment: try this regex `(?:\d{2}_){1,2}\d{4}|\d{4}(?=\.html)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the `\d{2}_` optional with the `?` character:

```js
const regex = /(\d{2}_)?(\d{2}_)?\d{4}\.html/;

console.log('01_01_2020.html'.match(regex));
console.log('01_2020.html'.match(regex));
console.log('2020.html'.match(regex));
console.log('abc.html'.match(regex));
```

---

You can also use `?:` to prevent capturing the groups:

```js
const regex = /(?:\d{2}_)?(?:\d{2}_)?\d{4}\.html/;

console.log('01_01_2020.html'.match(regex));
console.log('01_2020.html'.match(regex));
console.log('2020.html'.match(regex));
console.log('abc.html'.match(regex));
```

Comment: Hey, you have won the race. :D

Comment: This met my need. Especially preventing capturing the groups. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```js
const regex = /(\d{2}_)?(\d{2}_)?\d{4}\.html/;
console.log('01_01_2020.html'.match(regex));
console.log('01_2020.html'.match(regex));
console.log('2020.html'.match(regex));
console.log('abc.html'.match(regex));
```